# Should you capitalize run-in sentence?

Tags: grammar, capitalization, quotations

So I come up with a question in narration, and here's a few example:

**I know from her smile that she was saying "you look like an idiot" to me.**

**She was more likely than not dishing me out with “do this fool even know how to make a golem?” sarcasm.**

**At that moment, I heard someone shouting “Kill! Kill! Kill!” and saw that a crazy person running rampant on the street and stabbing the pedestrians.**

**Two of the nearby men complied and quickly grabbed the insane man down screaming “Let go of me!” over and over.**

I don't know what this thing is called, but I'm confused in whether capitalizing them or not. So if you can help, I will be the most grateful.

I know for a fact that a normal construction like this,
**He raised his eyebrows, saying, "Hey, that hat is mine."**
Is capitalized.

Comment: You seem to be confusing quoted speech with a [*run-on* sentence](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/independent_and_dependent_clauses/runonsentences.html). There is no "run-in" sentence.

Comment: If you look at this question, it's asking similar things about punctuating speech. Does this answer your question? [Do exclamation and question marks always end a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/494514/do-exclamation-and-question-marks-always-end-a-sentence)

Answer (score 2):

The quoted words are *direct speech.* The speaker's words should always begin with a capital letter, whatever their position in the sentence, so in your first example the woman's implied words should read "You look like an idiot".

Comment: Even if she's not speaking the word? I mean, she was only smiling that implies that meaning (You look like an idiot) to the the guy.

Comment: That's why I referred to her _implied_ words. Thoughts or imagined utterances are treated just the same as spoken words as regards punctuation.

Comment: I see, then what about the one where he is shouting "Kill! Kill! Kill!"? It's not a complete sentence, right? But there are three of them repeated. This is my last question.

Comment: A single word can be a sentence, for example "Yes." "What?" or a verb used as a command, as it is here.